# Is there a way to search for locked files in the finder?

Tags: snow-leopard, finder, smart-folders

The title pretty much says it all. Using the File Inspector I can see if a given file is locked or not, but I would like to be able to create a smart folder containing all the files in a given folder that are not locked.

(I need this as a convenience to quickly find the files I have checked out for editing on another machine which I am accessing through a shared folder)

Comment: I wanted to quickly answer "yes sure", checked the additional options and was surprised that there seems to be no option for searching for locked files in the finder. :-( I only found solutions for terminal like that one: http://macosx.com/tech-support/mac/finding-a-locked-file/21936.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/MetadataAttributesRef/Reference/CommonAttrs.html Goes over all the attributes spotlight has, and it looks like you could possibly create a smart folder with any of these attributes, unfortunately none of them mention locked file status.

`ls -lO | grep uchg` will give you a list of all the files in a folder which are locked or unchangeable, but only in the terminal.

Comment: If the terminal is an option, `$ find . -flags uchg` will recursively search for locked files ([source](https://superuser.com/a/647863)).